# IP packets fragment randomly

Tags: networking, ip

I've observed the strangest thing - the same packet, same size, send through the same interface sometimes gets send whole, and sometimes gets fragmented, as if it exceeded the interface MTU...

1472 packet fragmented:

```
10:10:24.537385 IP 192.168.56.1.35749 > 192.168.56.101.4444: UDP, length 1008
10:10:24.537589 IP 192.168.56.1.35749 > 192.168.56.101.4444: UDP, length 464
```

1472 packet not fragmented:

```
10:10:34.168099 IP 192.168.56.1.41252 > 192.168.56.101.44444: UDP, length 1472
```

This seems to happen randomly. Why does this happen?

The interface that sends the packet has `MTU 1500`, enough for 1472 udp. But the same thing happend for smaller packets. `tracepath` also shows mtu 1500 for this path.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, 3.13.0-46-generic

Comment: They're different protocols (port 4444 versus 44444), maybe the application is doing something different.

Comment: @Barmar no, sorry for the confusion, but this happens no matter which port sends the data

Comment: Those aren't fragmented packets, they're separate UDP datagrams. The UDP header is only in the first fragment, so there wouldn't be a port number in the second fragment.

Comment: I think you are right. I've checked and this "fragmentation" happens only to UDP packets, ICMP packets are not affected. I still do not understand why, to test various udp sizes I use this command: `printf "%0.s0" {1..1472} > /dev/udp/192.168.136.105/4448`

Comment: Like I said, it's related to the application. The first pair of packets must have been sent by a different application than the second packet, and it split it up in the application code.

Comment: Don't use `printf` when sending UDP. You have little control over when it flushes its output buffer. Each call to `write()` will turn into a separate UDP packet.

Comment: You were right, sending 1472 bytes without printf does not have this problem. If you post it as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: I don't know what to suggest as an alternative if you're sending from the CLI. You'd have to write your own application in a programming language that gives you more direct control.

Comment: @Barmar I've written a simple C program to test this, but also found that `cat 1472byte.file > /dev/udp/192.168.136.105/4448` works as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer for my problem was the one in a comment by @Barmar and he should get the props.

I was sending the packets from `cli` with a command that flushes it's output in segments, and that was the cause of my strange results.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and in my case this phenomenon is caused by GSO.

Use `skb_is_gso(skb)` to check the GSO status and you can disable GSO by using `skb_gso_reset(skb)`.